# Custom login using Django user model

Tags: python, django, authentication, model

I'm trying to make my custom login form using Django's user template.
What i'm trying to do is the authentication of a user using username and password.
Register works, every user is registered correctly, but when i'm trying to login using the correct fields, my:

```py
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

returns None as value.

Here is my def login_view in views.py
(i'm using logger to know what is going on)

```py
def login_view(request):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug('start')
    title = 'LOGIN'
    form = UserLoginForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('board.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        username= request.POST.get('username')
        password= request.POST.get('password')

        print(form.errors)

        if form.is_valid():
            logging.debug('form is valid')
            logging.debug('called form.save(), result=%s', UserLoginForm)
            logging.debug('username, result=%s', username)
            logging.debug('password, result=%s', password)
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            logging.debug('user, result=%s', user)
            ####
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                logging.debug('username, result=%s', username)
                logging.debug('password, result=%s', password)
                messages.info(request, "You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect('board.html')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
                logging.debug('first else')
                return redirect('/')
            ####
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            logging.debug('errore form: , result=%s', form.errors)
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
            logging.debug('second else')
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
            logging.debug('username, result=%s', username)
            logging.debug('password, result=%s', password)
            return redirect('/')


    return render(request=request,
                  template_name="login.html",
                  context={"form": form , "title":title})
```

And that's my forms.py

```py
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="username", help_text=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password',)


    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import logging
        logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log', level=logging.DEBUG)



        logging.debug('I'm in forms.py')

        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(self,username=username, password=password)
        logging.debug('sono dentro forms, user=%s', user)

        if user is not None:
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError('No user found')
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError('User is unable to login')

            return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

And that's the logger

```
DEBUG:root:inizio
DEBUG:root:i'm in forms
DEBUG:root:i'm in forms, user=None
DEBUG:root:form is valid
DEBUG:root:called form.save(), result=<class 'scrumboard.forms.UserLoginForm'>
DEBUG:root:username, result=a
DEBUG:root:password, result=123
DEBUG:root:user, result=None
DEBUG:root: first else
```

Data as username and password are correctly sended to logger, so the post works fine.
What i think is wrong is the action to search username and/or password in my database, and i'm already sure that these fields are stored in correctly.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I think i use authenticate wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The problem were in the way i was storing the password:

I was storing the field password as a normal string, without any encryption.

So i changed my register way with these lines in my register_view:

```
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            **user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))**
```

With this last line, the field password is being stored correctly, so now i can authenticate my user without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The form validates the data sent from the frontend. Without it, you are pulling "unclean" data from `request.POST.get('username')`. To get the cleaned (validated) username from the form, use `username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')` and `password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')` instead.

Comment: I think i have not understand what you're meaning. Forms sends data correctly, in fact, as my log shows, i've typed 'a' as username and '123' as password. These two data are stored in a rows of my db, but when i call authenticate passing this tuple, doesn't find the user and this is None, as shown in the log.